# Putting single attribute from group of entity objects into an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, objective-c-blocks

If I have an NSArray of custom objects (in this case Core Data objects), how would I put all the items of a particular attribute in another NSArray. Is there a way I can use blocks?

For instance, if the class is People, and one of the attributes is age, and there are five objects in the array of people, then the final NSArray would just show the ages:

```
{ 12, 45, 23, 43, 32 }
```

Order is not important.

Comment: you mean to say, you have an array of "People". People has a property called as "age". You want to have another array that would contain "ages" of these people?

Comment: There are several ways. @TimDean has showed you one of the correct ways. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** I have added a blocks based implementation too alongwith the selector based implementation.

What you are looking for is something equivalent to the "map" function from the functional world (something which, unfortunately, is not supported by Cocoa out of the box):

```
@interface NSArray (FunctionalUtils)
- (NSArray *)mapWithSelector:(SEL)selector;
- (NSArray *)mapWithBlock:(id (^)(id obj))block;
@end
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation NSArray (FunctionalUtils)

- (NSArray *)mapWithSelector:(SEL)selector {
  NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self count]];
  for (id object in self) {
    [result addObject:[object performSelector:selector]];
  }
  return [result autorelease];
}

- (NSArray *)mapWithBlock:(id (^)(id obj))block {
  NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self count]];
  for (id object in self) {
    [result addObject:block(object)];
  }
  return [result autorelease];
}

@end
```

Now, when you need to "map" from people to their ages, you can just do this:

```
ages = [people mapWithSelector:@selector(age)];
```

OR

```
ages = [people mapWithBlock:^(Person *p) { return [p age]; }];
```

The result, `ages`, will be a new `NSArray` containing just the ages of the people. In general, this will work for any sort of simple mapping operations that you might need.

**One caveat**: Since it returns an `NSArray`, the elements inside `ages` should be `NSNumber`, not a plain old integer. So for this to work, your `-age` selector should return an `NSNumber`, not an `int` or `NSInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each object has a method called "age" that returns an NSNumber *, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
-(NSArray *)createAgeArray:(NSArray *)peopleArray {
    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[peopleArray count]];
    [peopleArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id person, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
        [result addObject:[person age]];
    }];
    return [result autorelease];
}
```

Comment: This should work. Since people is an entity, the age property, i assume, to be NSNumber. Hence, it was directly added as an object to the array.